# Centering a DIV in CSS

Tags: html, css, position, center

Here is the link to a site I am working on for a friend - http://jayclarkephotography.com/

I am trying to center the logo. I have tried various ways, but am new to making websites, so I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this through CSS, tell the browser you want auto margins on the left and right, add this to the image tag

```
style="margin:0 auto;"
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `a` inside the header, add the following CSS:

```
display: block;
width: 340px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

You might want to ajust the padding of the header, because the logo is not dead center.